# Exploring c++ forward declarations of nested types and a standards compliance teaser?

Tags: visual-studio, llvm-clang, c++17

I recently, thanks to awesome [Jan 9th 2018 planet clang team work](http://planet.clang.org/) and others great articles, figured out how to configure my dev-setup to integrate llvm 7.0, visual studio 2017 15.5.6 for 32-bit and 64-bit Intel architecture.

*My motivation for this was forced by Microsoft's 15.4.X breaking std lib framework changes that rendered the Microsoft experimental **clang c2** front end (somewhat buggy anyway) to break.*

In the Intel setup I use LLVM tools to both compile and link PDB debuggable Windows code.
*See other posts I made on that topic for instructions on how to integrate everything so you can use latest updates to Visual Studio 2017 tools and debugging with latest 7.X builds of LLVM/clang. For those interested in full Windows 10 on ARM development (not UWP sillyness), I am separately still working the same setup for arm-32, arm-64 to all work together using LLVM tools as well as use Wine-ARM for Linux.*

Once done with that integration, I was looking to see what **LLVM 7.0 clang** allowed to be done without needing [P0289R0 Forward declarations of nested classes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf).

```
struct ds1; struct ds1::ds2;
```

I started fiddling around and wrote the ***sample below***. It compiles and runs correctly with clang-llvm 7.0. It will not compile (without errors) when using Microsoft's latest c++ front-ends.

So, I scratched my head wondering if it is actually legal c++ code. I often do that, as I use c++ in non-standard style with templates and forward references. *For example, I only use one **cpp** file per module and use includes within templates to minimize any forward declarations. That pattern avoids the need for **makefiles** and dramatically improves portability, compilation time, and often code generation quality. In effect, I use the **.cpp** file as a makefile with minimal to no macros and pure clang/gcc and c++ features.*

In asking myself if the code was actually legit c++ according to the standard, I re-read through standard. I concluded that yes it was standard compliant to template rules, but that would make Microsoft's compiler be non-compliant. So I wondered if others more knowledgeable might chime in and clarify the question.

Here is the code sample:
*(note it happens to also be intentionally infinitely recursive in a number of ways to test compiler detection)*

```
// P0289R0 clang Forward declarations of nested classes
//- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0289r0.pdf
// struct ds1; struct ds1::ds2;
struct nested1;
struct nested2;
// Code that references "nested1" here (could be pointer, but in template model this is more interesting case)
template <bool f_ta = true>
void foo(nested1& n1) {
  n1.run();
}
template <bool f_ta = true>
struct outer {
  struct inner {
    void run() {
      nested1 n1; nested2 n2;
      n2.test();
      foo(n1);
    }
  };
  void test() {
    nested1 n1;
    foo(n1);
  }
};
//using nested = outer::inner; // Must be defined at module-scope
//typedef outer::inner nested; // Must be defined at module-scope
struct nested1 : outer<>::inner { using super_t = outer<>::inner; using super_t::super_t; };
struct nested2 : outer<> { using super_t = outer<>; using super_t::super_t; };
bool fAutoRunIt = []() {
  nested2 a;
  a.test();
  return true;
}();
```

You can easily modify the example to **not be** recursive and still test out the other forward reference behavior.

Cheers, David